# Change folder icon color programmatically

Tags: c#, shell, icons, desktop.ini

I wanted to changed the color of folder icon of windows. Is that possible by any means of shell or just by modifying desktop.ini through C#?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do this programatically, I would start by looking at the Portable Executable file format (Wikipedia entry). The resources section (.rsrc, see section 6.9) should contain the icon. Using this information, you can write a tool to modify the icon.

Comment: Yes. I am interested to know (and I am sure it could be done through some developer) how programmatically change the color bitmaps of a icon file which contains usually more than one bitmap of the same icon. // Then I would like to know if there are any plans from Windows to change to vector icons.